# How to configure connection setting in window firewall For home use?

Tags: windows-firewall

I am asking for a non-IT users

If I have configured connection setting to use isolation authentication for both inbound and outbound for any protocol any IP and any port.
How to configure a not authenticate rule for non-IT user to browse and use gmail, outlook, Facebook and HSBC Hong Kong web only?

Comment: I do not think you are able to do that directly with the Windows Firewall. Can you use other applications too or are you looking to do it with a clean windows installation?

Comment: Your question is very unclear, lacking any details on your setup, configuration and target.

Comment: Actually clean window never online except activation. You can consider as clean window.  I am asking for my younger brother to enhance his computer security. I am asking for company computer. If only allow browse amazon account and EC2 and allow NordVPN. CDN and a pool of servers of google make this difficult to allow. It is like can only allow to web proxy or remote browser. Actually this originally is perfect because outbound rules can not block all unknown IP.